# Predict in Tensorflow 2.0 without keras and session

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to get the values of arrays in the dictionary self.tensor_dictionary. Session code looks like this:

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=self.graph) as sess:
            self.predictions_dict = sess.run(self.tensor_dictionary,
                                       feed_dict={self.image_graf_tensor: self.current_picture})
```

How to rewrite code using TF2 style without using sessions and keras?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything is done right, this syntax could become something like:

```py
self.preciction_dictionary = {}

for k, fcn in self.tensor_dictionary.items():
    self.preciction_dictionary[k] = fcn(self.current_picture)
```

or more simply

```py
self.preciction_dictionary  = {k: fcn(self.current_picture) for k, fcn in self.tensor_dictionary.items()}
```

What needs to be done right for this to work?

The items of `self.tensor_dictionary` need to be functions that accept arguments like `self.current_image`. If you want this to be 100% equivalent, the functions need to be decorated with `@tf.function` so that they are run in graph mode.

---

Explanation:

TF2 avoids using sessions, placeholders or graphs directly. This is done in favor of functions.

Example TF1 code:

```py
inp_arr = np.array(...)

inp = tf.placeholder(...)
a = tf.Variable(...)

b = tf.matmul(a, b)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    c = sess.run(b, feed_dict={inp: inp_arr}
```

What this code does is to run the op stored in variable `b` after substituting the `inp` placeholder with `inp_arr`. The same thing in TF2 would look like this:

```py
inp_arr = np.array(...)
b = tf.Variable(...)

@tf.function
def mul(a):
    return tf.matmul(a, b)

c = mul(a)
```

This way they **substituted** placeholders and sessions with functions. Additionally you don't handle the graph directly (i.e. `tf.Graph`), rather it is generated on its own through AutoGraph, by adding the `tf.function` decorator.

Comment: how am I supposed to know what to return in the decorated functions? The values of the tensor_dictionary contain tensors

Comment: If you think of it it's the same graph you had before. In TF1 you "ran" the last op in the graph, while in TF2 you must return it in a function. If I had more specific details on what these tensors contained I could say more...